# European date input in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, date, django-admin

Django has a DATE_FORMAT and a DATE_TIME_FORMAT options that allow us to choose which format to use when viewing dates, but doesn't apparently let me change the input format for the date when editing or adding in the Django Admin.

The default for the admin is: YYYY-MM-DD

But would be awesome to use: DD-MM-YYYY

Is this integrated in any case in i18n?
Can this be changed without a custom model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this idea I made new db.fields class EuDateField:

mydbfields.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms.fields import DEFAULT_DATE_INPUT_FORMATS
from django.db import models

class EuDateFormField(forms.DateField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update({'input_formats': ("%d.%m.%Y",)+DEFAULT_DATE_INPUT_FORMATS})
        super(EuDateFormField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class EuDateField(models.DateField):
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update({'form_class': EuDateFormField})
        return super(EuDateField, self).formfield(**kwargs)
```

Note that it adds my format (e.g. 31.12.2007) to existing "standard" django formats at first place.

Usage:

```
from mydbfields import EuDateField
class Person(models.Model):
    ...
    birthday   = EuDateField("Birthday", null=True, blank=True, help_text="")
```

In my case this renders good in admin, but most probably will in ModelForm too (haven't tried it).

My django version is:

```
>>> import django
>>> django.get_version()
u'1.1 alpha 1 SVN-10105'
```

Comment: Ok, this solution is nice, but how can I use it with AdminDateWidget? This Widget is a part of my MultiWidget.

Answer (score 11):

There is an official way to do this now since the closing of [Django ticket 6483](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6483) & release of Django 1.2.

If you have [`USE_L10N`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-USE_L10N) set to `False`, what you should do is specify the [`DATE_INPUT_FORMATS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3//ref/settings/#date-input-formats) and [`DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3//ref/settings/#datetime-input-formats) in your `settings.py`. Here are the settings I use for this, based on converting the defaults:

```
#dd/mm/yyyy and dd/mm/yy date & datetime input field settings
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%d-%m-%Y', '%d/%m/%Y', '%d/%m/%y', '%d %b %Y',
                      '%d %b, %Y', '%d %b %Y', '%d %b, %Y', '%d %B, %Y',
                      '%d %B %Y')
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', '%d/%m/%Y',
                          '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S', '%d/%m/%y %H:%M', '%d/%m/%y',
                          '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

If you have `USE_L10N` set to `True`, then you will need to use the [`FORMAT_MODULE_PATH`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#format-module-path) instead.

For example, my [`LANGUAGE_CODE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#language-code) is set to `en-au`, my site is called `golf`, and my `FORMAT_MODULE_PATH` is set to `golf.formats`, so my directory structure looks like this:

```
golf/
    settings.py
    ...
    formats/
        __init__.py
        en/
            __init__.py
            formats.py
```

and the `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` and `DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS` settings are in `formats.py` instead of `settings.py`.

Answer (score 5):

I've modified settings so that it disables l10n and set date format explicite:

```
USE_L10N = False
DATE_FORMAT = 'd-m-Y'
DATETIME_FORMAT = 'd-m-Y H:i'
```

You can set DATE_INPUT_FORMATS as well.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do this yourself for now, but it's quite easy to do with a custom form field class that sets the input_formats argument of DateField.  This should do it:

```
class MyDateField(forms.DateField):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault('input_formats', ("%d-%m-%Y",))
    super(MyDateField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Note that input_formats is a list, so you can specify multiple possibilities and it will try them in order when parsing user input.

Comment: I can apply this on my new forms, but, how can I override the default form field in the admin site?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is [not yet supported](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6483), as I understand it, so yes, you'll have to do some custom work for now.

Answer (score 0):

just beware not to write it as a string but as a tuple. 
eg:

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%d.%m.%Y',)
```

if you want to have only one valid way of writing date in a form.