# How to make Django's "DATETIME_FORMAT" active?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, datetime-format, django-settings

Where should `DATETIME_FORMAT` be placed for it to have effect
on the display of date-time in the Django admin site
(Django’s automatic admin interface)?

Documentation for `DATETIME_FORMAT`, on page
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/settings/, says:

```
"The default formatting to use for datetime fields on
Django admin change-list pages -- and, possibly, by
other parts of the system."
```

**Update 1**: `DATETIME_FORMAT` is broken (the value of it is
ignored), despite the documentation. Many years ago it
worked, but since then the Django implementations have been
broken wrt. this feature. It seems the Django community
can't decide how to fix it (but in the meantime I think they
should remove `DATETIME_FORMAT` from the documentation or add
a note about this problem to it).

I have put these lines into file "settings.py" of the
website/project (not the app), but it does not seem to have
any effect (after restarting the development server):

> DATETIME_FORMAT = 'Y-m-d H:i:sO'
>
> DATE_FORMAT     = 'Y-m-d'

As an example "June 29, 2009, 7:30 p.m." is displayed when
using Django admin site.

Django version is 1.0.2 final and Python version is 2.6.2
(64 bit). Platform: Windows XP 64 bit.

Stack Overflow question *[European date input in Django Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907351)* seems to be about the exact opposite problem (and thus an apparent
contradiction).

The full path to file "settings.py" is
"D:\dproj\MSQall\website\GoogleCodeHost\settings.py". I now
start the development server this way (in a Windows command
line window):

> cd D:\dproj\MSQall\website\GoogleCodeHost
>
> set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=GoogleCodeHost.settings
>
> python manage.py runserver 6800

There is no difference. Besides these are positively read
from file "settings.py":

> DATABASE_NAME
>
> INSTALLED_APPS
>
> TEMPLATE_DIRS
>
> MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES

"django-admin.py startproject XYZ" does not create file
"settings.py" containing `DATETIME_FORMAT` or `DATE_FORMAT`.
Perhaps there is a reason for that?

The sequence "d:", "cd D:\dproj\MSQall\website\GoogleCodeHost",
"python manage.py
shell", "from django.conf import settings",
"settings.DATE_FORMAT", "settings.DATETIME_FORMAT" outputs
(as expected):

```
'Y-m-d H:i:sO'
'Y-m-d'
```

So the content of file "settings.py" is being read, but does
not take effect in the Django Admin interface.

Comment: Do you have the settings.py designated as settings module?
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#designating-the-settings

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737146/django-template-date-format might be a dupe to this, but the question there is less precise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will solve the particular problem that is not possible
with DATETIME_FORMAT (as it is ignored in the current Django
implementations despite the documentation), is dirty too and
is similar to ayaz's answer (less global - will only affect
the admin site list view):

Right after the line

> (date_format, datetime_format,time_format) = get_date_formats()

in file (Django is usually in folder Lib/site-packages in
the Python installation)

> django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py

overwrite the value of datetime_format (for a
models.DateTimeField in the model):

> datetime_format = 'Y-m-d H:i:sO'

And for date-only fields:

> date_format     = 'Y-m-d'

Restart of the web-server (e.g. development server) or
logging out of the admin interface is **NOT** necessary for
this change to take effect. A simple refresh in the web-browser 
is all what is required.

Comment: [Good god...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpSqV.png) also Denmark fame link is broken

Answer (score 15):

With:

```
USE_L10N = False
```

`DATE_TIME` takes effect, since the localization of l10n overrides `DATETIME_FORMAT` and `DATE_FORMAT` as documented at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#date-format

Answer (score 7):

As Ciro Santilli told, localization format overrides `DATETIME_FORMAT` in settings when `USE_L10N = True`. But you can still override `DATETIME_FORMAT` and other date/time formats by [creating custom format files as described in Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/formatting/#creating-custom-format-files).

See detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39477478/258772).

> You can override `DATE_FORMAT`, `DATETIME_FORMAT`, `TIME_FORMAT` and other date/time formats when `USE_L10N = True` by [creating custom format files as described in Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/formatting/#creating-custom-format-files).
>
> In summary:
>
> 1. Set `FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = 'yourproject.formats'` in `settings.py`
> 2. Create directory structure `yourproject/formats/en` (replacing `en` with the corresponding ISO 639-1 locale code if you are using other locale than English) and add `__init__.py` files to all directories to make it a valid Python module
> 3. Add `formats.py` to the leaf directory, containing the format definitions you want to override, e.g. `DATE_FORMAT = 'j. F Y'`.
>
> Example from an actual project [here](https://github.com/mrts/foodbank-campaign/blob/master/src/foodbank/formats/et/formats.py).

Answer (score 2):

The two setting directives should be defined in `settings.py`. Could you ensure that the same `settings.py` that you are editing is being read when you start the development server?

You could always drop to the Python interactive shell by running `python manage.py shell`, and run these commands to ensure whether the date/time format values are getting through fine:

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.DATE_FORMAT
settings.DATETIME_FORMAT
```

Ok, I forgot to look it up, but [ticket #2203](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2203) deals with this. Unfortunately, the ticket remains in pending state.

I remember that for a project that used a certain trunk revision of the 0.97 branch of Django, I worked around that by overwriting the `date_format` and `datetime_format` values in the `get_date_formats()` function inside `django/utils/translation/trans_real.py`. It was dirty, but I had already been using a custom Django of sorts for that project, so didn't see anything going wrong in hacking it trifle more.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experiments with **Django 4.2.1**, [DATETIME_FORMAT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#datetime-format) for [DateTimeField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield) works only in Django Templates. In addition, [DATE_FORMAT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#date-format) for [DateField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#datefield) and [TIME_FORMAT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#time-format) for [TimeField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#timefield) work in Django Templates. *You can see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76402876/short-datetime-format-and-short-date-format-dont-work-in-django-templates-w) explaining it.

And, [DATE_INPUT_FORMATS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#date-input-formats) for `DateTimeField()` and `DateField()` and [TIME_INPUT_FORMATS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#std-setting-TIME_INPUT_FORMATS) for `DateTimeField()` and `TimeField()` work in Django Admin. *[DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#datetime-input-formats) doesn't work to any parts of a Django project and you can see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76400054/datetime-input-formats-doesnt-work-in-django-admin-while-date-input-formats) explaining it.

*You need to set [USE_L10N](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#use-l10n) `False` in `settings.py` to make these settings above work because `USE_L10N` is prior to them.