# Django: Use of DATE_FORMAT, DATETIME_FORMAT, TIME_FORMAT in settings.py?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin, datetime-format

I would like to globally (through my entire site, admin and front-end) adjust the way dates and time are displayed to my likings, but I cannot figure out what is going on with the DATE_FORMAT, DATETIME_FORMAT and TIME_FORMAT variables in `settings.py`.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004109/django-how-to-make-datetime-format-active) it says that the settings are ignored. The question is over a year old though. In the Django documentation it says they can be used when you have `USE_L10N = True` and apparently [something changed](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.2/#date-format-helper-functions) in Django 1.2. According to [this](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/a957f19d608bf868/26d504de45f8aa39?lnk=gst&q=DATE_FORMAT+settings#26d504de45f8aa39) however there might be a bug.

I am currently using Django 1.2 and when I have `USE_L10N = True` it just ignores the date(time) format in settings.py. When I have `USE_L10N = False` it also seems to ignore them.

Is there a way to globally customize the date and time display? Or should I create my own custom formats file as Karen suggests in the Django Users Google Group post?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Had same problem, solution is [simple and documented](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date).  Whenever you render a date, you need to specify you want the template to render it as a date/time/short_date/datetime (e.g., `{{ some_date_var | date }}` and then it will render it as specified with `DATE_FORMAT` in your settings.py

Example:

```
>>> from django.conf import settings  # imported to show my variables in settings.py 
>>> settings.DATE_FORMAT #  - showing my values; I modified this value
'm/d/Y'
>>> settings.TIME_FORMAT
'P'
>>> settings.DATETIME_FORMAT
'N j, Y, P'
>>> from django.template import Template, Context
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> c = Context(dict(moon = datetime(1969, 7, 20, 20, 17, 39))) # Create context with datetime to render in a template
>>> print c['moon'] # This is the default format of a printing datetime object 
1969-07-20 20:17:39
>>> print Template("default formatting : {{ moon }}\n"
                   "use DATE_FORMAT : {{ moon|date }}\n"
                   "use TIME_FORMAT : {{ moon|time }}\n"
                   "use DATETIME_FORMAT: {{ moon|date:'DATETIME_FORMAT' }}\n"
                   "use SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT: {{ moon|date:'SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT' }}"
                   ).render(c)
default formatting : 1969-07-20 20:17:39
use DATE_FORMAT : 07/20/1969
use TIME_FORMAT : 8:17 p.m.
use DATETIME_FORMAT: July 20, 1969, 8:17 p.m.
use SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT: 07/20/1969 8:17 p.m.
```

This makes sense; e.g., the template needs to know whether it should use the `DATE_FORMAT` or the `SHORT_DATE_FORMAT` or whatever.

Answer (score 11):

Searching through the source shows that DATETIME_FORMAT, etc., are only used when `django.utils.formats.localize()` is called, and that only seems to be called when `django.template.VariableNode`s are rendered.

I'm not sure when exactly `VariableNode`s are used in template rendering, but I would guess that if you have `settings.USE_L10N` turned on and you have a `VariableNode`, it will be localized.

`localize` looks like this:

```
def localize(value):
    """
    Checks if value is a localizable type (date, number...) and returns it
    formatted as a string using current locale format
    """
    if settings.USE_L10N:
        if isinstance(value, (decimal.Decimal, float, int)):
            return number_format(value)
        elif isinstance(value, datetime.datetime):
            return date_format(value, 'DATETIME_FORMAT')
        elif isinstance(value, datetime.date):
            return date_format(value)
        elif isinstance(value, datetime.time):
            return time_format(value, 'TIME_FORMAT')
    return value
```

To answer your question, I'd probably write a quick context processor that called `localize()` on everything in the context.

Answer (score 9):

You can override `DATE_FORMAT`, `DATETIME_FORMAT`, `TIME_FORMAT` and other date/time formats when `USE_L10N = True` by [creating custom format files as described in Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/formatting/#creating-custom-format-files).

In summary:

1. Set `FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = 'yourproject.formats'` in `settings.py`
2. Create directory structure `yourproject/formats/en` (replacing `en` with the corresponding ISO 639-1 locale code if you are using other locale than English) and add `__init__.py` files to all directories to make it a valid Python module
3. Add `formats.py` to the leaf directory, containing the format definitions you want to override, e.g. `DATE_FORMAT = 'j. F Y'`.

Example from an actual project [here](https://github.com/mrts/foodbank-campaign/blob/master/src/foodbank/formats/et/formats.py).

Answer (score 4):

A late response, but hopefully this will help anyone else searching for this.
By setting USE_L10N = True in your settings, Django looks for locale specific formats, giving them precedence over non-locale related settings.

The solution:  *(to display 30/12/2017 on a DateField)*

```
from django.conf.locale.en import formats as en_formats

en_formats.DATE_FORMAT = "%d/%m/%Y"
```

and for inputs (to accept 30/12/2017 or 30-12-2017)

```
en_formats.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d/%m/%Y', '%d-%m-%Y']
```

Reference:  https://mounirmesselmeni.github.io/2014/11/06/date-format-in-django-admin/

**tested on Django==1.10.7*

Comment: Isn't it easier to create custom format files as described in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/formatting/#creating-custom-format-files?

Answer (score 0):

You can partially format date and time but not entirely in a Django project according to my experiments with **Django 4.2.1**.

In Django Admin, set [DATE_INPUT_FORMATS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#date-input-formats) to format [DateTimeField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield) and [DateField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#datefield) and set [TIME_INPUT_FORMATS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#std-setting-TIME_INPUT_FORMATS) to format `DateTimeField()` and [TimeField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#timefield) in `settings.py`. *[DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#datetime-input-formats) doesn't work to any parts of a Django project and you can see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76400054/datetime-input-formats-doesnt-work-in-django-admin-while-date-input-formats) explaining these 3 settings.

In Django Templates, set [DATETIME_FORMAT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#datetime-format), [DATE_FORMAT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#date-format) and [TIME_FORMAT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#time-format) to format `DateTimeField()`, `DateField()` and `TimeField()` respectively in `settings.py` and you can see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76402876/short-datetime-format-and-short-date-format-dont-work-in-django-templates-w) explaining these 3 settings in addition to other 2 settings.

*You need to set [USE_L10N](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#use-l10n) `False` in `settings.py` to make these settings above work because `USE_L10N` is prior to them.