# "DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS" doesn't work in Django Admin while "DATE_INPUT_FORMATS" and "TIME_INPUT_FORMATS" do

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, datetime-format

I use [DateTimeField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield), [DateField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#datefield) and [TimeField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#timefield) in `MyModel` class as shown below. *I use **Django 4.2.1**:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    datetime = models.DateTimeField() # Here
    date = models.DateField() # Here
    time = models.TimeField() # Here
```

Then, I set [DATE_INPUT_FORMATS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#date-input-formats) and [TIME_INPUT_FORMATS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#time-input-formats) and set [USE_L10N](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#use-l10n) `False` to make `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` and `TIME_INPUT_FORMATS` work in `settings.py` as shown below:

```py
# "settings.py"

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = False # Here

USE_TZ = True

DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ["%m/%d/%Y"] # '10/25/2023' # Here
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ["%H:%M"] # '14:30' # Here
```

Then, `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` and `TIME_INPUT_FORMATS` work in Django Admin as shown below:

[image]

Next, I set [DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#std-setting-DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS) and set `USE_L10N` `False` to make `DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS` work in `settings.py` as shown below:

```py
# "settings.py"

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = False # Here

USE_TZ = True

DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ["%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"] # '10/25/2023 14:30'
```

But, `DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS` does not work in Django Admin as shown below:

[image]

In addition, from a `MyModel` objcet, I get and print `datetime`, `date` and `time` and pass them to `index.html` in `test()` in `views.py` as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import MyModel

def test(request):
    obj = MyModel.objects.all()[0]
    print(obj.datetime)
    print(obj.date)
    print(obj.time)
    return render(
        request, 
        'index.html', 
        {"datetime": obj.datetime, "date": obj.date, "time": obj.time}
    )
```

But, all `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS`, `TIME_INPUT_FORMATS` and `DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS` don't work according to console as shown below:

```
2023-10-25 14:30:15+00:00
2023-10-25
14:30:15
```

Next, I show `datetime`, `date` and `time` in `index.html` as shown below:

```
# "index.html"

{{ datetime }}<br/>
{{ date }}<br/>
{{ time }}
```

But, all `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS`, `TIME_INPUT_FORMATS` and `DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS` don't work according to browser as shown below:

```
Oct. 25, 2023, 2:30 p.m.
Oct. 25, 2023
2:30 p.m.
```

My questions:

1. How can I make `DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS` work in Django Admin?
2. Why doesn't `DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS` work in Django Admin?
3. If `DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS` doesn't work in Django Admin, where does `DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS` work?

Comment: Did you figure this out? Having a similar problem.