# "SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT" and "SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" don't work in Django Templates while "DATETIME_FORMAT", "DATE_FORMAT" and "TIME_FORMAT" do

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, datetime-format

I use [DateTimeField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield), [DateField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#datefield) and [TimeField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#timefield) in `MyModel` class as shown below. *I use **Django 4.2.1**:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    datetime = models.DateTimeField() # Here
    date = models.DateField() # Here
    time = models.TimeField() # Here

    def __str__(self):
        return "MyModel"
```

Then, I set [DATETIME_FORMAT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#datetime-format), [DATE_FORMAT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#date-format) and [TIME_FORMAT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#time-format) and set [USE_L10N](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#use-l10n) `False` to make `DATETIME_FORMAT`, `DATE_FORMAT` and `TIME_FORMAT` work in `settings.py` as shown below:

```py
# "settings.py"

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = False # Here

USE_TZ = True

DATETIME_FORMAT = "m/j/Y, P" # 10/25/2023, 2:30 p.m. # Here
DATE_FORMAT = "F jS, Y" # October 25th, 2023 # Here
TIME_FORMAT = "H:i:s" # 14:30:15 # Here
```

Then, from a `MyModel` objcet, I get `datetime`, `date` and `time` and pass them to `index.html` in `test()` in `views.py` as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import MyModel

def test(request):
    obj = MyModel.objects.all()[0]
    return render(
        request, 
        'index.html', 
        {"datetime": obj.datetime, "date": obj.date, "time": obj.time}
    )
```

Then, I show `datetime`, `date` and `time` in `index.html` as shown below:

```
# "index.html"

{{ datetime }}<br/>
{{ date }}<br/>
{{ time }}
```

Now, all `DATETIME_FORMAT`, `DATE_FORMAT` and `TIME_FORMAT` work according to browser as shown below:

```
10/25/2023, 2:30 p.m.
October 25th, 2023
14:30:15
```

Next, I set [SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#short-datetime-format) and [SHORT_DATE_FORMAT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#short-date-format) and set `USE_L10N` `False` to make `SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT` and `SHORT_DATE_FORMAT` work in `settings.py` as shown below:

```py
# "settings.py"

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = False # Here

USE_TZ = True

SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT = 'm/j/Y, P' # 10/25/2023, 2:30 p.m. # Here
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT = 'F jS, Y' # October 25th, 2023 # Here
```

Then, I show `datetime`, `date` and `time` in `index.html` as shown below:

```
# "index.html"

{{ datetime }}<br/>
{{ date }}<br/>
{{ time }}
```

Now, both `SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT` and `SHORT_DATE_FORMAT` do not work according to browser as shown below:

```
Oct. 25, 2023, 2:30 p.m.
Oct. 25, 2023
2:30 p.m.
```

In addition, from a `MyModel` objcet, I get and print `datetime`, `date` and `time` in `test()` in `views.py` as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import MyModel

def test(request):
    obj = MyModel.objects.all()[0]
    print(obj.datetime) # Here
    print(obj.date) # Here
    print(obj.time) # Here
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

But, all `DATETIME_FORMAT`, `DATE_FORMAT`, `TIME_FORMAT`, `SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT` and `SHORT_DATE_FORMAT` don't work according to console as shown below:

```
2023-10-25 14:30:15+00:00
2023-10-25
14:30:15
```

Also, all `DATETIME_FORMAT`, `DATE_FORMAT`, `TIME_FORMAT`, `SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT` and `SHORT_DATE_FORMAT` don't work in Django Admin as shown below:

[image]

My questions:

1. How can I make `SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT` and `SHORT_DATE_FORMAT` work in Django Templates?
2. Why don't `SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT` and `SHORT_DATE_FORMAT` work in Django Templates?
3. If `SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT` and `SHORT_DATE_FORMAT` don't work in Django Templates, where do `SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT` and `SHORT_DATE_FORMAT` work?