# How can I change the default Django date template format?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have dates in ISO 8601 format in the database, `%Y-%m-%d`. However, when the date is passed on to the template, it comes out as something like `Oct. 16, 2011`.

Is there a way that I can manipulate the format to whatever I want?

Answer (score 381, accepted):

Within your template, you can use Django's [`date`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#date) filter. E.g.:

```
<p>Birthday: {{ birthday|date:"M d, Y" }}</p>
```

Gives:

> Birthday: Jan 29, 1983

More formatting examples in the [date filter docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#date).

Comment: I think this works only if date is provideded as a datetime object. What if it is just a string passed from the view?

Comment: For an arbitrary string containing a date/time, I'd probably parse it into a python datetime in the view code. (Or even earlier if possible -- wherever that date string first arrives in my code.) But if you really want to use strings to pass datetimes to your Django templates, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33188293/647002) looks helpful.

Comment: Perfect above example to use in the template file.

Answer (score 61):

[`date` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#date)

[`settings.DATE_FORMAT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#date-format)

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd change that in the settings file

Comment: Link to docs isn't really an answer, so downvoted this and upvoted medmunds' answer.

Answer (score 39):

**Set both `DATE_FORMAT` and `USE_L10N`**

To make changes for the entire site in Django 1.4.1 add:

```
DATE_FORMAT = "Y-m-d"
```

to your `settings.py` file and edit:

```
USE_L10N = False
```

since l10n overrides `DATE_FORMAT`

This is documented at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-format

Answer (score 35):

Just use this:

```
{{you_date_field|date:'Y-m-d'}}
```

This will show something like *2016-10-16*.
You can use the format as you want.

Answer (score 13):

You need a [date template filter](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/references/2016/06/21/date-filter.html).

E.g:

```
<td>Joined {{user.date_created|date:"F Y" }}<td>
```

This returns `Joined December 2018`.

Answer (score 12):

If you need to show a short date and time (11/08/2018 03:23 a.m.), you can do it like this:

```
{{your_date_field|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT"}} {{your_date_field|time:"h:i a"}}
```

Details for this tag is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#s-now) and more about dates according to the given format is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#date).

Example:

```
<small class="text-muted">Last updated: {{your_date_field|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT"}} {{your_date_field|time:"h:i a"}}</small>
```

Answer (score 10):

In order to change the date format in the *views.py* file and then assign it to template:

```
# get the object details 
home = Home.objects.get(home_id=homeid)

# get the start date
_startDate = home.home_startdate.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

# assign it to template 
return render_to_response('showme.html', {'home_startdate':_startDate},  context_instance=RequestContext(request) )
```

Answer (score 4):

```
{{yourDate|date:'*Prefered Format*'}}
```

Example:

```
{{yourDate|date:'F d, Y'}}
```

For the preferred format: [Built-in template tags and filters, date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#date)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an error in calling a Date value in a Django template, try this

```
{{ViewfieldValue.CreateModelValue|date:"M d, Y" }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{{your_date|date:'Y-m-d'}}
```

This will show something like 2022-12-02. You can use the format as you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% load temp_tags %}

     <div class="d-flex ">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control me-2 w-25 show_error"  name="lender_dob_day" aria-describedby=""
                        {% if lender_dob %} value="{{ lender_dob|split:'-'|last }}" {% else %} value="" {% endif %} placeholder="DD">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control me-2 w-25 show_error"  name="lender_dob_month" aria-describedby=""
                        {% if lender_dob %} value="{{ lender_dob|split:'-'|slice:'1:2'|first }}" {% else %} value="" {% endif %} placeholder="MM">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control flex-1 show_error" name="lender_dob_year" aria-describedby=""
                        {% if lender_dob %} value="{{ lender_dob|split:'-'|first }}" {% else %} value="" {% endif %} placeholder="YYYY">
                    </div>






@register.filter
def split(value, delimiter):
    return value.split(delimiter)
```

Answer (score -1):

**Here is date format changing on django template:**

**Code:**

```
<h5>Event date is: {{ event_date|date:"M d, Y" }}</h5>
```

**The output will be like this:**
Aug 17, 2022