# How to change django datetime format output?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a datetime object. This is my template file:

```
<ul>
<li>{{ sale.validity }}</li>
</ul>
```

and the output i'm getting is in the format:

> July 18, 2012, midnight

I would really like to change the output to be numerical in the format: day-month-year so for example the above would be changed to:

> 18-07-2012

Can someone point me out to the right direction on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the default Django date template format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737146/how-can-i-change-the-default-django-date-template-format)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Per [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date), you can use a `date` filter to format date:

```
{{ sale.validity|date:"d-m-Y"}}
```

Additionally, you can also set [DATE_FORMAT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#date-format) (or DATETIME_FORMAT) setting to set a project-wide default for displaying such values if `USE_L10N` is False. If it's true, you'll want to have a look at this [documentation on format localization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/formatting/).

Comment: this is great. waiting for the time to pass to mark it as correct thank you