# Django-models Change format of dateField as "DD-MM-YYY"

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, date-format

I am using django-model's-dateField in my django-project and wanna change my dateFields format in admin view.

Currently (default) django gives format in **YYYY-MM-DD** but i want to modify that and in need of **DD-MM-YYYY**

I've been struggled too much in this and till no solution.

Also providing my code, may help..

my **settings.py** have:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

**models.py**:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User_Profile')
    mobile = models.BigIntegerField()
    alternative_number = models.BigIntegerField()
    DOB = models.DateField()
```

and then i register it in admin

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vqsev.png) on admin

as you can see in my admin page there is a dateField with format 2019-11-04 but i want in form of DD-MM-YYYY as 04-11-2019.

I tried **LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de-at'** that would work for me but the problem is, it changes the local language also.

refering a similer post:
*[Django - change default presentation format of model date field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25204299/django-change-default-presentation-format-of-model-date-field)*

Comment: What did you think of the links in the answers to this question: [how-to-change-django-datetime-format-output/11578330#11578330](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578311/how-to-change-django-datetime-format-output/11578330#11578330)

Comment: Hi @TamoorSalah-U-Din, these are for forms.datefield, i tried for mine but didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

add this to your settings.py

```
DATE_FORMAT = '%d-%m-%y'
```

for more check this [date format](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-format)

Answer (score 1):

You need just to override Django’s defaults locale settings. Add this to your settings.py file

```
from django.conf.locale.es import formats as es_formats

es_formats.DATETIME_FORMAT = "d M Y H:i:s"
```

Comment: This is not working for my case can you please elaborate what the package django.conf.locals. **es**

Is the *es* for LANGUAGE_CODE or what..
in my case i have LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us" does this related with this.

Comment: `es` will refer to Spain / Spanish. Replacing `es` with `en` may work, you might need to play around with it a little.

Answer (score 1):

fahim kazi was right: to define a models.DateField format, you need DATE_FORMAT, not DATETIME_FORMAT.

Yet Naveen Varshney was also right: not DATE_FORMAT nor DATETIME_FORMAT work without specifying the language, with es_formats for instance.

Therefore, from the combination of both answers, put the following in settings:

```
es_formats.DATE_FORMAT = 'd-m-y'
```

(Also `'%d-%m-%y'` printed `%01-%08-%20` thus the `%` is not needed).

Thanks both.