# Django/Python - showing months in words instead of numbers

Tags: python, django

I'm having a little issue regarding showing months in words, instead of numbers.
Right my blog is showing "13-03-2013", but I want it to be "13-March-2013"

Here are the things I did to get as far as I am now:
I added the date in my models:

```
pub_date = models.DateTimeField("Gepubliceerd", auto_now_add=True)
```

When I call the variable pub_date in my blog template it shows in numbers(13-03-2013).

Is there an easy way to change the numbers to the actual month names?
I've been thinking about creating a tuple with every month name in it, let it run a check which number of the month there is in pub_date, and according to that, use the right month from the tuple.

But for some reason I feel there has to be a easier way. But so far I haven't been successful finding another solution.

Hopefully some awsome people have experience with this!

Thx in advance!

Comment: see this http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior and this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-format

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737146/django-template-date-format

Comment: format the date value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use template filter `date` provided with Django. See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date) on how to use it.

If you want to use this date format in exactly this one place just use

```
{{ pub_date|date:'d-F-Y' }
```

If that's the default format you want everywhere use the `DATE_FORMAT` and `SHORT_DATE_FORMAT` settings. Read the docs for more info.

Comment: Thanks! for some i failed badly in the research i did before. I can change the {{ pub_date|date:'d-m-Y' }} to {{ pub_date|date:'d-M-Y' }}.
the capital M makes it show the word instead of the number! Thx for all the help anyway! ^^

Answer (score 1):

so after some more research after this post (which i should've done before making this question) i came to the following:

```
{{ pub_date|date:'d-m-Y' }}
```

is how i call the date. Within that, you can play around with date format provided by Django itself. if you change the 'm' to a capital 'M', it will display the month in letters. But There are alot more possibility's explained over here:

[Read here all about the Django date format](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date)

once again, sorry for asking a question to quickly