# In Django template how to separate Date and time from DateTimeField?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I want to print only the date on my Django template. This is my model.

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(User)
    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    article  = models.ForeignKey(Article)
```

Now to print both date and time on a template I can use {{object.pub_date}} to print. 
But I only want to print the date, not the time. 
Is there a way to do so in Django Templates ?

Comment: there are so many answer that you could find on stackoverflow please do some search before you ask question [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737146/django-template-date-format)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
{{ object.pub_date|date:"D d M Y" }} {{ object.pub_date|time:"H:i" }}
```

all options explained: [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#date)