# Django templatetags ISO to date

Tags: python, django, django-templates

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737146/django-template-date-format) but distinctly different, in my opinion.

I have an object that has some datetime attributes. In order to serialize it and store as a JSON string, I call the `.isoformat` method (using a custom JSON encoder).

The other way around, I expected Django template tags to be able to resolve this for me. I have a JSON object that I convert to a dictionary by calling `json.loads`. The resulting attribute has the value `2015-10-07T14:57:00.501597+00:00` when I simply call it as `{{ my_object.date }}`. When I pass it to the `date` template tag, however, I get no output at all. I'm trying `{{ my_object.date | date }}` but also things like `{{ my_object.date | date:'Y-m-d' }}`.

Is date not able to convert these values? I distinctly remember doing this at some point, but am not sure on the specifics..

Is there a way to debug this properly? Right now I'm just not seeing any output, and nothing appears in the logs either.

Comment: Make sure `my_object` is available in the template context. What's the result of `{{ my_object }}`?

Comment: That prints the entire dictionary. What's more, as I mentioned above, `{{ my_object.date }}` prints `2015-10-07T14:57:00.501597+00:00`, confirming that the key is correct as well.

Comment: It seems like that's a string. The `date` filter works on datetime objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not convert it to a datetime instance before passing it to the template? Then you could use the [date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#date) filter in the template to output whatever you want. If you don't/can't do that, you'll have to write a custom filter tag to read the isoformat date and output it how you want to.

Example using [dateutil library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil):

```
from django import template
import dateutil

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='to_date')
def to_date(value):
    return dateutil.parser.parse(value)
```

Docs for [custom filter tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters).

Comment: Hm.. it seems you're right, and this is the proper way. I'm surprised that `datetime.isoformat` is in the standard library, but there is no way to convert back to `datetime` though.

Comment: Yeah, maybe one day dateutil can be moved into standard library, it's pretty cool. Please accept the answer.

Comment: Update: There is `datetime.fromisoformat()` method since Python 3.7