# How to change Django date format to dd/ mm/ yy?

Tags: jquery, html, date, django-forms, django-templates

In forms.py:

```
class DobForm(forms.ModelForm)  
    dob = forms.DateField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}),required=True,input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y',])

    class Meta:
        model = Dob
```

In my html:

```
$(function() {$(".datepicker").datepicker({ maxDate: '0',dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' })});</script>
```

Its thorwing error in the form: Enter a valid date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django template date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737146/django-template-date-format)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make the formats the same for both django and jquery.

Try this for the DateField (django):

```
...,input_formats=['%d-%m-%Y',])
```

and in the html use:

```
...,dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy' })});</script>
```

I hope this works.

Comment: nice answer but in html its 'yy' not yyyy

Comment: Can you make your code more specific? Thanks a lot! :)