# Django: Changing the date format from JSON data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm currently trying to teach myself Django and I'm a little confused on how to modify data from a web API.

For example I request an api with a url:

```
api.example.com/events?location=....
```

And I get JSON data

```
{'data':
  [
    {
       'name': 'blah'
       'date': '2019-03-22'
    },
    {
       'name': 'blah2'
       'date': '2019-03-23'
    },
  ]
}
```

The date is outputted as "yyyy-mm-dd" and I want to change it to "mm dd yyyy". Would I have to put the JSON data into a model? If so, how would I go about doing so?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737146/how-to-change-the-default-django-date-template-format

Comment: Would this work in my scenario? Date isn't in a model for it to know it is an datetime object.

Comment: Is the JSON data generated by your django app or an external website? If the data is from an external website you can change DATE_INPUT_FORMAT in the settings: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-input-formats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've the same problem I do this simply convert String to a new datetime object.

```
from datetime import datetime

def create_date(year, month, day):
    """
    Converts a Json Object Date to Datetime object
    :param year:
    :param month:
    :param day:
    :return:
        Date
    """
    if not isinstance(year, int):
        raise TypeError('year is not int')

    if not isinstance(month, int):
        raise TypeError('month is not int')

    if not isinstance(day, int):
        raise TypeError('day is not int')

    date_value = "{year}-{month}-{day}".format(year=year,
                                            month=month,
                                            day=day)

    return datetime.strptime(date_value, '%Y-%m-%d')
```