# Django format DateTimeField output to {YYYY-MM-DD} {HH:MM AM/PM}

Tags: python, django, django-models

Im using the auto_now_add field for DateTimeField in django and I'm displaying a date like this `2019-05-08T09:23:09.424129Z` and I want to convert it to this format `{YYYY-MM-DD} {HH:MM AM/PM}` without changing the model since we are in production.

Most of the examples I found on the web require you to add something in the model any workarounds?

**Model:**

```
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Where do you want to display your date ? In the admin, in a template ?

Comment: Yeah, same question, it depends on what you want to achieve. I believe you may find [this answer useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737146/how-to-change-the-default-django-date-template-format) if it's only about displaying date and datetime in your view/template/page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display it on a template, you should use the [date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#date) filter :

```
{{ instance.created|date:"Y-m-d h:i A" }}
```

Or in Python, you can use the [strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) function :

```
print(instance.created.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p"))
```