# Can I edit the datetime field before saving in database in django?

Tags: python, django

I am uploading an excelsheet in which date is in format 08-10-2020(DD-MM-YYYY). When it's saved in the database, it becomes, Oct. 8,2020 8:50 p.m.
But I want the date to be saved in YYYY-MM-DD format.
Is this posssible?

My models.py looks like this:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    bday = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    year = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the default Django date template format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737146/how-can-i-change-the-default-django-date-template-format)

Comment: A database is not about the format. Internally it is often stored in a binary format. So you should not care about this at the model level. You can configure settins like `DATE_FORMAT` and `DATETIME_FORMAT` to specify how to *render* it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#date-format

Comment: Actually, I have to extract the email whose bday matches with today's date..so how to do it?

Comment: @AshutoshKrishna: I think a birthday probably should use a `DateField`, not a `DateTimeField`.

Comment: Okay, so can you help me how to compare the birthday with today's date