# django forms.DateInput not responding to dd/mm/yyyy format

Tags: python, django, django-forms

currently I'm having issues with getting input validation working as expected with Django `DateInput`

As per my understanding, the default format for `DateInput` is `"%Y-%m-%d"` if left untouched, however explicitly setting the format to `"%d/%m/%Y"` still causes validation errors.

Here are some examples

> Input: 25/03/1981
> Expected: Valid date (We expect this value to **not** trigger a validation error)
> Actual: Enter a valid date.

> Input: 1/07/1981
> Expected: Date parsed as 1st July
> Actual: Date parsed as 7th January
> (i.e date and month are parsed in place of each other)

forms.py

```
class PatientForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        # Make form look nice from here
        model = Patient
        fields = ('PAS_number', 'first_name', 'middle_name',
                  'surname', 'DOB', 'priority_code',
                  'patient_information', 'patient_status')

        widgets = {
            'PAS_number': forms.NumberInput(
                attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'middle_name': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'surname': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'DOB': forms.DateInput(
                format=('%d/%m/%Y'), attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'priority_code': forms.Select(
                attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'patient_information': forms.Textarea(
                attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'patient_status': forms.Select(
                attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),

        }
```

Comment: Try Reading this, it might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737146/how-can-i-change-the-default-django-date-template-format

Answer (score 2):

The `format` kwarg on the `DateInput` merely controls the display of the initial value - it doesn't control how submitted data is processed. From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/widgets/#dateinput):

> **format**: The format in which this field’s initial value will be displayed.

You have two choices:

1. Modify the [`DATE_INPUT_FORMATS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#date-input-formats) setting to specify the formats you want to accept for input - this will affect all date inputs.
2. Specify `input_formats` on the [form field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/#datefield) (not its widget). On a `ModelForm`, this means [overriding the default field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields).