# DateFormat in Django and App Engine?

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I have a slight issue with dates in [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_(web_framework)) and [Google App Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine):

I have the following class because I want date input in the form of DD/MM/YY:

```
class MyForm(ModelForm): 
      mydate = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%d-%m-%y', '%d/%m/%y']) 
      class Meta: 
          model = MyObject
```

This works for entering into the datastore. 
However when I use a generic view to edit the data the form comes back in the format of YYYY-MM-DD. Any ideas on how to change that?

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907351/european-date-input-in-django-admin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

forms.DateInput takes a format keyword argument, and this can be used to control the format that is represented (I seem to remember, anyway):

```
class MyForm(ModelForm): 
      mydate = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(format="%d/%m/%y")) 
      class Meta: 
          model = MyObject
```

I ended up subclassing both the Field and the Widget, as I wanted to be able to control the formats even more.

Answer (score 1):

A `DateTimeField` will return a `datetime.datetime` as its value, so you can use any of the usual methods defined in that module for formatting the data. In Django templates, you can use the `date`, or `time` filters:

```
{{my_obj.mydate|date:"D d M Y"}}
```

Which prints something like:

```
Wed 09 Jan 2008
```

(See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date for details)

Comment: I know that but I am talking about the format in an Edit box when using a generic view. I get it back in the format of YYYY-MM-DD in the form

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
def date_format(self, instance, **kwargs):
 return getattr(instance,self.name) and getattr(instance,self.name).strftime('%d %m %Y')

from google.appengine.ext.db.djangoforms import DateProperty 
 DateProperty.get_value_for_form = date_format
```