# Django admin: change date and datetime format

Tags: django, date, django-admin, date-formatting

The default date format in Django admin is YYYY-MM-DD, I would like to change it to DD-MM-YYYY. Based on an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1437608/9035706) to a similar question I could update the validators to accept the new format, but if I opened an existing object, the date was still shown as YYYY-MM-DD and the JS date picker returned dates in this format, too. How to overcome these issues?

Comment: Do you have USE_L10N = True?

Comment: Yes, I do have `USE_L10N = True`. However, if necessary perhaps I can turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

After you set `USE_L10N = False`, add this

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = [
'%d-%m-%Y', '%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y',
'%b %d %Y', '%b %d, %Y',  
'%d %b %Y', '%d %b, %Y',  
'%B %d %Y', '%B %d, %Y',  
'%d %B %Y', '%d %B, %Y',  
]
```

Change the first format if you want something else. [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#date-input-formats)